# PHP cURL connect to back-office with CSRF Token and execute POST submit

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies, php-curl

I'm trying to connect to an interface in order to perform a submit request (to export a .csv file). 
This back-office is protected with a CSRF Token, so first, i managed to get the unique token every time I want to connect :
**Code to Get CSRF Token (it works):**

```
$url = 'https://contact.carvivo.com/login';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$request = $dom->loadHTMLFile($url); // $request === false
$DOMxpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$value = $DOMxpath->query("//input[@name='_csrf_token']/@value");
$list=array();
    foreach($value as $v){
       $list[]=$v->nodeValue;
      }
$_csrf_token = $list[0];
```

Now, I would like to connect to this interface and would like to perform a POST submit to https://contact.carvivo.com/login_check with 4 parameters like so : 
**Code to connect to this back-office : (doesn't seems to work)**

```
// Login to interface
$params = array(
  '_username'=>'my_login',
  '_password' => 'my_paswword',
  '_csrf_token' => $_csrf_token,
  '_submit' => 'Connexion'
);
$param = http_build_query($params);

// Curl login
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://contact.carvivo.com/login_check");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

In cookie.txt, there is an entry :

```
#HttpOnly_contact.carvivo.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   PHPSESSID   8f851310185ae7c0fd72aed84bfba924
```

But it seems that the connexion is not established (I have a visual redirect to login page when I execute the code).

**So, what am I missing ?

How can I perform another request to another page (https://contact.carvivo.com/export/ not accessible without this first authentication) with cookies stored in cookie.txt ?**